# Get all anchor texts of links in specific class with file_get_contents

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to retrieve the anchor texts of this links:

```
<a class="c-shadow" href="some-random-link">text 1</a>
<a class="c-shadow" href="some-random-link">text 2</a>
<a class="c-shadow" href="some-random-link">text 3</a>
<a class="c-shadow" href="some-random-link">text 4</a>
<a class="c-shadow" href="some-random-link">text 5</a>
```

Considering that all this links have in common the same class name ( c-shadow ), how can I retrieve all the anchor texts? I need to find text 1, text 2, text 3, text 4, text 5...

Comment: To ask an On Topic question, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Use Symfony's [`DomCrawler`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse that html with DOMDocument & XPath.  The selector syntax within XPath is pretty straight forward -- the `a` tag is followed by the `[@class='target_class_name']`.  The foreach loop will loop through the qualifying nodes, then it is just a matter of extracting the node values as you iterate.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cn9p1))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<a class="c-shadow" href="some-random-link">text 1</a>
<a class="c-shadow" href="some-random-link">text 2</a>
<a class="c-shadow" href="some-random-link">text 3</a>
<a class="c-shadow" href="some-random-link">text 4</a>
<a class="c-shadow" href="some-random-link">text 5</a>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->evaluate("//a[@class='c-shadow']") as $node) {
  $result[] = $node->nodeValue;
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'text 1',
  1 => 'text 2',
  2 => 'text 3',
  3 => 'text 4',
  4 => 'text 5',
)
```

---

Alternatively, the textNode can be isolated as well.

```
foreach ($xpath->query("//a[@class='c-shadow']/text()") as $textNode) {
    $result[] = $textNode->nodeValue;
}
```